# Can I host a static website on Azure storage and still have an email address for that domain?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-static-website-hosting

Is it possible to host mydomain.com as a static website on Azure storage, and still setup email address admin@mydomain.com?

I believe that CNAME is required for hosting on Azure storage, but this won't work with email

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - seems like this is possible by using an ANAME record in Azure DNS... I'll have to move my domain registration across to test this, but will report back when I eventually get around to it

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can host an static website to Azure Storage.You can serve static content (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and image files) directly from a container in a general-purpose V2 or BlockBlobStorage account.

You can simply follow this ***[Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to?tabs=azure-portal#portal-find-url)*** to host your static website to Azure Storage container and you will primary and secondry endpoint to access the website.

You can map your both endpoint to the customer for that please also refer this [***document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: Yes, I know that I can host a static website on Azure storage... my question is how can I host a static website on Azure storage AND setup email for that domain.

The issue is that the documentation states that I need to create a CNAME record to point domain to Azure, however if I have CNAME record I cannot have a MX record (for email)